# Android change CheckBoxes on Adapter dont work correctly

Tags: android

In my simple adapater, I want to manage checkboxes on items. When I click on a check box I change a status and when I'm scrolling the checkbox status is false and i can't fix my code to resolve this problem

```
public class ContactsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactsAdapter.CustomContactsViewHolder> {
    private OnCardClickListener onCardClickListener;
    private List<UserPhoneContacts> list = Collections.emptyList();
    private       Context            context;
    private       Realm              realm;
    public static OnSelectedContacts onSelectedContacts;
    private Map<String, Boolean> checkBoxStates = new HashMap<>();

    public ContactsAdapter(List<UserPhoneContacts> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
        this.realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public CustomContactsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View                     v      = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.contact_item, parent, false);
        CustomContactsViewHolder holder = new CustomContactsViewHolder(v);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomContactsViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.contact_name.setText(list.get(position).getDisplayName());
        holder.contact_mobile.setText(list.get(position).getMobileNumber());

        Boolean checkedState = checkBoxStates.get(list.get(position).getMobileNumber());
        holder.select_contact.setChecked(checkedState == null ? false : checkedState);
        holder.select_contact.setTag(position);
        holder.select_contact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onChange((Integer) v.getTag());
            }
        });
    }

    private void onChange(int position) {
        final UserPhoneContacts item = list.get(position);
        if (item == null) {
            return;
        }
        boolean checkedState = checkBoxStates.get(list.get(position).getMobileNumber()) != null;
        checkBoxStates.put(item.getMobileNumber(), !checkedState);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    public void setData(List<UserPhoneContacts> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public static class CustomContactsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.contact_name)
        TextView contact_name;

        @BindView(R.id.contact_mobile)
        TextView contact_mobile;

        @BindView(R.id.contact_photo)
        CircleImageView contact_photo;

        @BindView(R.id.select_contact)
        CheckBox select_contact;

        CustomContactsViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        }
    }
}
```

what happen when i clicking on checkbox?

click->**checked**, click->**unchecked**, click-> **unchecked**, click-> **unchecked**, click-> **unchecked**

**after unchecked checkbox i can't change checkbox state after that by click on that**

Comment: In `onChange()` method add `notifyDatasetChanged()` after `checkBoxStates.put(item.getMobileNumber(), checked);` this line

Comment: @Anil i get this error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling`

Comment: On scroll every time setOnCheckedChangeListener is getting called, try to check with readyandroid answer.

Comment: This line of code[holder.select_contact.setChecked(checkedState == null ? false : true);] you had copied wrong from readyandroid answer, please check the answer and update it. From your line of code on scroll it will set everytime true to the checkbox if mobilenumber value is not null

Comment: use view tags and hashmap to maintain check uncheck of each checkbox in the list

Comment: @AmrutBidri could you fix my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I made your CustomContactsViewHolder class as non static class, and did some changes regarding click events and setting data again to check and uncheck, once check with full code by taking your code as a backup.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ContactsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactsAdapter.CustomContactsViewHolder> {
    private OnCardClickListener onCardClickListener;
    private List<UserPhoneContacts> list = Collections.emptyList();
    private Context context;
    private       Realm              realm;
    public static OnSelectedContacts onSelectedContacts;
    private Map<String, Boolean> checkBoxStates = new HashMap<>();

    public ContactsAdapter(List<UserPhoneContacts> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
        this.realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public CustomContactsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v      = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.contact_item, parent, false);
        CustomContactsViewHolder holder = new CustomContactsViewHolder(v);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomContactsViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.contact_name.setText(list.get(position).getDisplayName());
        holder.contact_mobile.setText(list.get(position).getMobileNumber());
        boolean checkedState = checkBoxStates.containsKey(list.get(position).getMobileNumber())?checkBoxStates.get(list.get(position).getMobileNumber()):false;
        holder.select_contact.setChecked(checkedState);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    public void setData(List<UserPhoneContacts> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public class CustomContactsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        @BindView(R.id.contact_name)
        TextView contact_name;

        @BindView(R.id.contact_mobile)
        TextView contact_mobile;

        @BindView(R.id.contact_photo)
        CircleImageView contact_photo;

        @BindView(R.id.select_contact)
        CheckBox select_contact;


        CustomContactsViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        }

        @OnClick(R.id.select_contact)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.select_contact:
                    final UserPhoneContacts item = list.get(position);
                    if (item == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    boolean checkedState = checkBoxStates.containsKey(list.get(position).getMobileNumber())?checkBoxStates.get(list.get(position).getMobileNumber()):false;
                    ((CheckBox)v).setChecked(!checkedState);
                    checkBoxStates.put(item.getMobileNumber(), !checkedState);
                    ContactsAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when i click again on checked check box and the state is will be unchecked after check again on that state don't change

Comment: LogCat: `E/checkedState: false
E/checkBoxStates: {09122331743=true}
E/checkedState: true
E/checkBoxStates: {09122331743=false}
E/checkedState: true
E/checkBoxStates: {09122331743=false}` and log places are `boolean checkedState = checkBoxStates.get(list.get(position).getMobileNumber()) == null ? false : true;
        Log.e("checkedState ", checkedState + "");
        checkBoxStates.put(item.getMobileNumber(), !checkedState);
        Log.e("checkBoxStates ", checkBoxStates.toString());
        notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: i updated my code with your post, but it doesnt work correctly for check and uncheck again. i dont have any problem on scrolling list now

Comment: I only change `boolean` to `Boolean` on this line of code: `Boolean checkedState = checkBoxStates.get(list.get(position).getMobileNumber());`

Comment: Did you check my latest comment in your questioned post, please check once and let me know?

Comment: my post updated with your comment and your post, but it doesnt work correclty on check and uncheck again sir. please review my post

Comment: I checked your latest code. Can you add your full adapter class with CustomContactsViewHolder?

Comment: I seems the issue was with static CustomContactsViewHolder class, it should be non static.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a separate `Map<String, Boolean>` list to maintain whether your `CheckBox` is selected or not. Try the simple trick below. But you need to update your `UserPhoneContacts` model class as follows.

```
public class UserPhoneContacts {

  // other variables

  private boolean isSelected = false;    // add this

  // your class constructor and other getter/setter methods

  // add below getter method
  public boolean isSelected() {
    return this.isSelected;
  }

  // add below setter method
  public void setSelected(boolean isSelected) {
    this.isSelected = isSelected;
  }
}
```

Change your `ContactAdapter` class like this

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomContactsViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    ...
    final UserPhoneContacts upc = list.get(position);
    holder.select_contact.setChecked(upc.isSelected() ? true : false);

    holder.select_contact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            upc.setSelected(!upc.isSelected());
            holder.view.setChecked(upc.isSelected() ? true : false);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: i have to create `Map` sir, because i'm using `Realm` database solution and that want to change data on database

Comment: Ok, you can use <Map>. Use above logic to check whether the `CheckBox` is selected or not. Based on the boolean value that's returned by the model class you can update `Map` entry, right?

Comment: yes, my logic of code is correct but it doesnt work correctly when i try to click multiple on that to change check box state, my post updated

Comment: Use `onChange(position);` instead of `onChange((Integer) v.getTag());` this might be the problem.

Comment: no sir, my check box state dont change on `onChange` function after change once

Answer (score 0):

The leading cause of your problem is **onChange** method.

```
private void onChange(int position) {
    final UserPhoneContacts item = list.get(position);
    if (item == null) {
        return;
    }
    boolean checkedState = checkBoxStates.get(list.get(position).getMobileNumber()) != null;
    checkBoxStates.put(item.getMobileNumber(), !checkedState);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

For example, firstly you click position 3 item, `checkBoxStates.get(3) return null`, so `!checkedState` will be true.

Secondly you click position 3, `checkBoxStates.get(3) == True`, `checkedState = (True != null) = true`, so `!checkedState` will false.

Thirdly you click position 3, `checkBoxStates.get(3) == False`, `checkedState = (False != null) = true`, so `!checkedState` also will false, the new state will also be unchecked.

The **fixed** code should be as following:

```
private void onChange(int position) {
    final UserPhoneContacts item = list.get(position);
    if (item == null) {
        return;
    }
    Boolean lastCheckedState = checkBoxStates.get(list.get(position).getMobileNumber());
    boolean checkedState = (null == lastCheckedState) ? false : lastCheckedState;
    checkBoxStates.put(item.getMobileNumber(), !checkedState);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: I tested your code, but it doesn't work correctly, after click on checkbox, the state nerver change